# How to make system clock to synchronize?

Tags: ntp, timekeeping, system-clock

I bought a new RPi 4 model B.

When doing the setup and setting an Internet connection, the RPi told me that the clock could not synchronize. After a couple of attempts I continued anyway, and obviusly the time and date are wrong now and I can't get them right.

This is what I get when

```
$ timedatectl 
                Local time: jue 2022-09-22 06:45:34 CEST
            Universal time: jue 2022-09-22 06:45:34 UTC
                  RTC time: n/a
                 Time zone: Europe/Madrid (CEST, +0200)
 System clock synchronized: no
               NTP service: active
           RTC in local TZ: no
```

System clock is not synchronized, although there's an Internet connection. How do I sync it?

*EDIT
As requested this is the output when

```
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-09-22 08:18:33 CEST; 12min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
   Main PID: 1063 (systemd-timesyn)
     Status: "Idle."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1830)
        CPU: 117ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
             └─1063 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

sep 22 08:18:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
sep 22 08:18:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
sep 22 08:18:43 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[1063]: Timed out waiting for reply from 10.28.64.1:123 (10.28.64.1).
sep 22 08:19:26 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[1063]: Timed out waiting for reply from 10.28.64.1:123 (10.28.64.1).
sep 22 08:20:40 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[1063]: Timed out waiting for reply from 10.28.64.1:123 (10.28.64.1).
sep 22 08:22:59 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[1063]: Timed out waiting for reply from 10.28.64.1:123 (10.28.64.1).
sep 22 08:27:25 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[1063]: Timed out waiting for reply from 10.28.64.1:123 (10.28.64.1).
```

Comment: This happens automatically DO NOTHING (other than normal setup)!

What OS did you install?

"When doing the setup and setting an Internet connection" what did you ACTUALLY do?

Do you have a working internet connection?

Comment: I installed Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit and followed the steps... Didn't do anything else. Yes, internet connection works

Comment: Edit in the output from `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I think he meant execute that command, and show the output of that command in your question

Comment: You seem reluctant to explain your system. You DO NOT appear to have a working network (unless you have a local time server).

Comment: I posted the question from the Raspberry, it is connected to the Internet. I already told you, brand new RPi, installed Raspberry Pi OS 64 bits and just followed the steps when installing, nothing more (setting user name, internet connection and time zone).