# Raspberry Pi 5 won't sychronize date and time

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, ntp, timekeeping, pi-5, systemd-timesyncd

I used the RPi Imager on my Mac to setup RPi OS 64-bit (the recommended version for me). Immediately after booting for the first time, I noticed that the date is stuck on 12/5/2023 (the date of the last release) and the time is also wrong. [Basically the same as this issue.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/139382/how-to-make-system-clock-to-synchronize) I'm new to this, but I believe it is affecting my ability to update and install various things. I've tried many of the suggestions I found online such as:

- reconfiguring the file at `/etc/systemd/timesync.conf`
- `sudo systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd`
- `sudo timedatectl set-ntp true`

I've also verified that I have internet connection. I know I could also manually reset the date and time, but I'd like a more permanent solution. Is this a common problem when starting up out of the box or is there some other issue that I may not be aware of?

EDIT:

I reflashed it and still have the same problem:
`timedatectl status` returns:

```
Local time: Tue 2023-12-05 00:31:45 EST
Universal Time: Tue 2023-12-05 05:31:45 UTC
RTC time: Thu 1970-01-01 00:06:24
Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -050)
System clock synchronized: no
NTP service: active
RTC in local TZ: no
```

I've also updated `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` the only changes are uncommenting all the lines and adding NTP=us.pool.ntp.org:

```
[Time]
NTP=us.pool.ntp.org
FallbackNTP=0.debian.pool.ntp.org 1.debian.pool.ntp.org 2.debian.pool.ntp.org 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
RootDistanceMax=5
PollIntervalMinSec=32
PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
ConnectionRetrySec=30
SaveIntervalSec=60
```

`sudo systemctl status system-timesyncd` returns

```
systemd-timesync.service - Network Time Synchronization
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesync.dservice; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-12-05 00:44:01 EST; 9min ago
Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
Main PID: 2043 (systemd-timesyn)
Status: "Connecting to time server 216.229.4.69:123 (us.pool.ntp.org)."
Tasks 2 (limit: 9250)
CPU: 57ms
CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service

Dec 05 00:44:01 [host] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization...
Dec 05 00:44:01 [host] systemd[1]: Started systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization.
Dec 05 00:44:11 [host] system-timesyncd[2101]: Timed out waiting for reply from 216.229.4.69:123 (us.pool.ntp.org).
Dec 05 00:44:21 [host] system-timesyncd[2101]: Timed out waiting for reply from 69.10.223.132:123 (us.pool.ntp.org).
Dec 05 00:44:32 [host] system-timesyncd[2101]: Timed out waiting for reply from 162.159.200.1:123 (us.pool.ntp.org).
Dec 05 00:44:42 [host] system-timesyncd[2101]: Timed out waiting for reply from 198.60.22.240:123 (us.pool.ntp.org).
Dec 05 00:45:24 [host] system-timesyncd[2101]: Timed out waiting for reply from 129.250.35.250:123 (us.pool.ntp.org).
Dec 05 00:45:35 [host] system-timesyncd[2101]: Timed out waiting for reply from 72.46.53.234:123 (us.pool.ntp.org).
Dec 05 00:45:45 [host] system-timesyncd[2101]: Timed out waiting for reply from 72.14.183.39:123 (us.pool.ntp.org).
Dec 05 00:45:55 [host] system-timesyncd[2101]: Timed out waiting for reply from 198.137.202.56:123 (us.pool.ntp.org).
```

Comment: as per the "basically same" link - what is the contents of `/etc/systemd/timesync.conf` now that you changed it? what is the output of `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`? what is the output of `timedatectl` - of course, the pi5 has an onboard RTC, so that may play a part in the solution too

Comment: @Milliways I didn't do any sort of custom configurations when connecting the RPi to the network. I'm using the RPi desktop and it shows it is connected, I'm also able to ping various websites, as well as use the browser. My laptop and phone are connected to the same network with no issues.

Comment: @JaromandaX I edited the post with more details about the ```timesyncd.conf``` and the outputs of ```timedatectl``` and ```systemctl status systemd-timesyncd```

Comment: what's the result of `ping us.pool.ntp.org`

Comment: try copying the fallbackNTP values to NTP (not sure why the fallback isn't even tried!) - I suspect you're "too far" (in network terms) from the US ntp pool - if the result of the above ping tells you `TTL expired in transit` then that would be the case ... you are in the USofA right?

Comment: hmmm, that's odd, I was getting a TTL expired to us.pool.ntp.org, and now I'm not (I'm not in the US and A and never used those NTP servers for anything) - ahh, I see now, multiple IP's - some work, some don't

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, I am in the USA eastern time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a networking issue not a time issue (possibly external to your Pi unless you have an error in network configuration).

If you set time (and have a RTC battery) it should work until the networking issue is resolved.